# Why tables are not created at destination database when using DMBS_STREAMS_ADM.MAINATIAN_TABLES procedure?

Tags: database-replication, datapump, oracle-streams

I am implementing an Oracle Streams environment that replicates DML changes on some tables.

I used the procedure **DBMS_STREAMS_ADM.MAINTAIN_TABLES** with the instantiation as DBMS_STREAMS_ADM.INSTANTIATION_TABLE_NETWORK, all the blocks of the procedure executed successfully, however the tables were not created at the destination database.

As stated in the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_streams_adm.htm#ARPLS68776):

> If this parameter is set to DBMS_STREAMS_ADM.INSTANTIATION_TABLE or DBMS_STREAMS_ADM.INSTANTIATION_TABLE_NETWORK, then the tables being instantiated must exist at the source database, and the tablespaces that contain the tables must exist at the destination database.

**Details:**

1. A database link from destination database to source database exists.
2. The tables exist in the source database and also the tablespace exist in the destination database.
3. The user SCOTT **does not exist** in the destination database.
4. Source database is Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
5. Destination database is Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production

**Main Code:**

```
DECLARE
  tables DBMS_UTILITY.UNCL_ARRAY;
  i      number := 1;
  j      number := 1;
  iscn  NUMBER;

BEGIN

  FOR c IN (select table_name from config_tables) LOOP
    tables(i) := c.table_name;
    i := i + 1;
  END LOOP;

  DBMS_STREAMS_ADM.MAINTAIN_TABLES(table_names                  => tables,
                                   source_directory_object      => NULL,
                                   destination_directory_object => NULL,
                                   source_database              => 'db1_global_name',
                                   destination_database         => 'db2_global_name',
                                   perform_actions              => TRUE,
                                   capture_name       => 'DML_Capture_Src',
                                   capture_queue_name => 'strmadmin.dml_streams_queue',
                                   propagation_name   => 'DML_Propagation',
                                   apply_name         => 'DML_Apply_Dest',
                                   apply_queue_name   => 'strmadmin.dml_streams_queue',

                                   bi_directional => FALSE,
                                   include_ddl    => FALSE,
                                   instantiation  => DBMS_STREAMS_ADM.INSTANTIATION_TABLE_NETWORK);
END;
/
```

The code generated 14 blocks, the 7th block (which uses datapump)

```
-- 
-- Datapump TABLE MODE IMPORT (NETWORK)
-- 
DECLARE
  h1                NUMBER := NULL; -- data pump job handle
  name_expr_list    VARCHAR2(32767); -- for metadata_filter
  object_name       dbms_utility.uncl_array; -- object names
  cnt               NUMBER;
  object_owner      VARCHAR2(30); -- owner
  job_state         VARCHAR2(30); -- job state
  status            ku$_Status; -- data pump status
  job_not_exist     exception;
  pragma            exception_init(job_not_exist, -31626);
  local_compat            v$parameter.value%TYPE;
  remote_compat            v$parameter.value%TYPE;
  min_compat            v$parameter.value%TYPE;
  ind               NUMBER; 
  le                ku$_LogEntry;  -- For WIP and error messages
  js                ku$_JobStatus; -- The job status from get_status 
  jd                ku$_JobDesc; 
-- The job description from get_status
BEGIN

  object_name(1) := 'DEPT';
  object_name(2) := 'SALGRADE';
  object_owner := 'SCOTT';
  FOR idx IN 1..2 LOOP
    SELECT COUNT(1) INTO cnt FROM all_tables@"db2_global_name"
      WHERE owner = object_owner AND table_name = object_name(idx);
    -- table does not exist locally, need instantiation
    IF cnt = 0 THEN
      IF name_expr_list IS NULL THEN
        name_expr_list := '(';
      ELSE
        name_expr_list := name_expr_list ||',';
      END IF;
      name_expr_list := name_expr_list||''''||object_name(idx)||'''';
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  IF name_expr_list IS NOT NULL THEN
    name_expr_list := name_expr_list || ')';
  ELSE
    COMMIT;
    RETURN;
  END IF;

  select value into local_compat from v$parameter@"db1_global_name"
  where name = 'compatible';
  select value into remote_compat from v$parameter@"db2_global_name"
  where name = 'compatible';
  IF TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(local_compat, '.', '0')) > TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(remote_compat, '.', '0')) THEN
    min_compat := remote_compat;
  ELSE
    min_compat := local_compat;
  END IF;
  h1 := dbms_datapump.open(operation=>'IMPORT',job_mode=>'TABLE',
    remote_link=>'db1_global_name',
    job_name=>NULL, version=> min_compat);



  dbms_datapump.metadata_filter(
    handle=>h1,
    name=>'NAME_EXPR',
    value=>'IN'||name_expr_list);
  dbms_datapump.metadata_filter(
    handle=>h1,
    name=>'SCHEMA_EXPR',
    value=>'IN'||'(''SCOTT'')');

  dbms_datapump.start_job(h1);

  job_state := 'UNDEFINED';
  BEGIN
    WHILE (job_state != 'COMPLETED') AND (job_state != 'STOPPED') LOOP
      status := dbms_datapump.get_status(
        handle => h1,
        mask => dbms_datapump.ku$_status_job_error +
                dbms_datapump.ku$_status_job_status +
                dbms_datapump.ku$_status_wip,
        timeout => -1);
      job_state := status.job_status.state;
      dbms_lock.sleep(10);
    END LOOP;
  EXCEPTION WHEN job_not_exist THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('job finished');
  END;
  COMMIT;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
  dbms_output.put_line('Exception, sql code = ' || SQLCODE || ', error message: ' || SQLERRM);
  dbms_output.put_line( dbms_utility.format_error_stack);
  dbms_output.put_line( dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace);

  IF h1 IS NOT NULL THEN 
    BEGIN 
      dbms_datapump.get_status( 
        handle    => h1, 
        mask      => dbms_datapump.ku$_status_job_error + 
                     dbms_datapump.ku$_status_job_status +
                     dbms_datapump.ku$_status_wip, 
        timeout   => -1, 
        job_state => job_state,
        status     => status );

      dbms_output.put_line('Data pump job status: ' || job_state);
      le := status.wip; 
      IF le IS NULL THEN 
        dbms_output.put_line('WIP info is NULL'); 
      ELSE 
        dbms_output.put_line('WIP info:'); 
        ind := le.FIRST; 
        WHILE ind IS NOT NULL LOOP 
          dbms_output.put_line(le(ind).LogText); 
          ind := le.NEXT(ind); 
        END LOOP; 
      END IF; 

      le := status.error; 
      IF le IS NULL THEN 
        dbms_output.put_line('Error info is NULL'); 
      ELSE 
        dbms_output.put_line('Error info:'); 
        ind := le.FIRST; 
        WHILE ind IS NOT NULL LOOP 
          dbms_output.put_line(le(ind).LogText); 
          ind := le.NEXT(ind); 
        END LOOP; 
      END IF; 
    EXCEPTION  
      WHEN job_not_exist THEN 
        dbms_output.put_line('Data pump job finished');
      WHEN OTHERS THEN RAISE; 
    END; 
  END IF; 
  ROLLBACK;
  RAISE;
END;
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show your code, rather than just describing it. You have copied an excerpt from the documentation suggesting what may be wrong - can you provide any insight as to which one may be relevant to your problem?

Comment: ok, i will update the question with the code in a while ...

Comment: When i created the user scott at the destination database, the tables where created and populated with data :D

Comment: If you have found the answer to you question you can add it yourself and accept it.